# c++ why does the pointer references by a std::shared_ptr get destroyed when the preceeding step throws an exception

Tags: c++

Currently I have a own version of a linked list in a `std::unordered_map<key,List<shared_ptr<t>>>` (where t is some type). I insert stuff like so:

```
void addTo(const Key &key, t* ptr)
{
    if(ptr==nullptr||ptr==NULL){
       throw "this is not a real exception that I am using"
   }
    try
    {
        this->getList(key).addNew(std::shared_ptr<t>(ptr));
    }
    catch(std::out_of_range ex)
    {
        this->addList(key,(std::shared_ptr<t>(ptr));
    }
}
```

However, I recently noticed that when the getList throws a out_of_range exception (which it always does if the map doesnt have a key like that in it) then the ptr gets deleted. Now it would make sense if the shared_ptr was created before getList is called, but why would that be the case?

I have verfied this by simply seperating this->getList and addNew like so:

```
const List<shared_ptr<t>> l& = this->getList(key);
l.addNew(etc etc);
```

When writing it like this, nothing happens to the pointer.

This leads me to conclude that the shared_ptr gets created first, which would mean that c++ processes instancing first? To me that doesnt make a while lot of sense.

**What are the exact rules for the order in which c++ does these kind of statements and why is it not instancing the shared_ptr AFTER ->getList (what is the reason for doing it differently)?**

Comment: The idea of using smart pointers it give an answer with code instead of documentation to the question "Who _owns_ that resource?". In order to use smart pointers efficiently, you need to learn about resource property managment. Take some time to do so.

Comment: The guy who creates the object that ptr points to should also create the shared_ptr and deliver it to your addTo(). Use shared_ptr's "everywhere"  or don't use them at all. You always need to keep at least one shared_ptr to the object alive.

Comment: If you're wondering about evaluation order and sequencing, then see e.g. [this evaluation order and sequencing reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), as well as [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176333/440558) (with [this follow up for C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4183735/440558) and later).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for giving me the first actual in context comment instead of making snarky comments about code of which they miss half the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order of execution between `std::shared_ptr<t>(ptr)` and `getList(key)` is unspecified in:

```
this->getList(key).addNew(std::shared_ptr<t>(ptr));
```

It might change from one compiler to other or even from one call to another.

C++17 adds more rules for evaluation order; you should have your expected order of evaluation guaranteed since this version.